# US - How much money can I send abroad, and how?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international-transfer, working-abroad, brazil

I am a Brazilian citizen and I am in the US with an L-1 (intra-company transfer employee) visa. My wife is British and a permanent resident of Brazil.

I have remainings of a mortgage in Brazil. I must send around US$400 per month to my Brazilian account in order to pay for it. Obviously when I receive bonuses at work I would like to send much more so I can pay it off.

My questions are:

- How much money can I send abroad if I'm a US resident without a green card?
- Do I need to pay taxes after a certain limit? If so, where can I find the information about how much and how to do it?
- Does having a green card or being a citizen somehow make a difference to the rules? If so, what are the differences?
- I've been using Xoom to transfer the money from my US current account to my Brazilian current account. Any problems with that vs. a wire transfer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your money, and if you can - if asked - prove that you legally made it, there is *no limit*.

You pay taxes on your income, so sending it into the world is tax free.

Your citizenship is not relevant for that.